Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration
I am using the below dependencies in my build.gradle but still this exception.
springBootVersion = '2.7.18'
springCloudVersion = '2021.0.9'

compile("commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2")
compile("commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6")
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache')
compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis')
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-config')
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix')
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-vault-config')
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap')
compile("io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2:1.7.0")
compile("io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-reactor:1.7.0")

I have read through lot of posts but did not found the root cause for this.
Appreciate any help.
